# How to define an optional word in pyparse grammar?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm parsing sql code objects for the object name and for views I noticed that there are optional keywords that could throw my grammar off. I think I need to be able to define an optional keyword but I have not found a way to do so.

**For example**

```
viewDefinition = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW" + Word( alphas+"_", alphanums+"_") 
forceviewLine = "CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VW_MY_TEST_VIEW"

print(forceviewLine,"->", viewDefinition.parseString(forceviewLine))
viewname = viewDefinition.parseString(forceviewLine)[1]
```

Because the grammar doesn't fit anymore I'd encounter the following error

pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Is there a way to define an optional keyword on the grammar that could come before the keyword VIEW and that I can get the VW_MY_TEST_VIEW code object name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thought it might be useful for others so I'm answering myself.

```
COR = CaselessLiteral('CREATE OR REPLACE') 
optFORCEkw = Optional(CaselessLiteral('FORCE'))
V = CaselessLiteral('VIEW')


forceviewLine = "CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VW_MY_TEST_VIEW"
normalviewLine = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_MY_TEST_VIEW"

newGrammer2 = COR + optFORCEkw + V + Word( alphas+"_", alphanums+"_") 
print(forceviewLine,"->", newGrammer2.parseString(forceviewLine))
print(normalviewLine,"->", newGrammer2.parseString(normalviewLine))
```

Comment: There are 2 changes I'd suggest. First break up any expression that is 2 or more words with a space into separate expressions which are then added together. This allow pyparsing to do whitespace skipping between the expressions, in case you have a statement with 2 spaces between the words, or a line break between the words. Second, when parsing a syntax like SQL, use CaselessKeyword instead of CaselessLiteral, to enforce word breaks before and after the word; otherwise you could match table named "VIEW1" as the VIEW keyword. Thus: `COR=CaselessKeyword('CREATE') + CaselessKeyword('OR') + etc.`

Comment: You'll find a couple of SQL-related parsers in the examples directory of the pyparsing GitHub repo: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples

Comment: Also look in to using `runTests` for testing out your parsers: `newGrammer2.runTests([normalviewLine, forceviewLine])` will echo the input string and show the parsed values, or show the exception with a marker where the parser stopped working.